# What are those magic symbols?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Having found a nice [vector graphics for magic symbols](http://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4430&sid=a4157beb902583b681496f74398d506e), I wonder what the symbols on the second-to-last row are:

[image: Magic symbols]

I recognize tap, untap, infinite and half, and the last one as the earlier white, but what are the others?

Comment: I voted to close this question because the link appears to be dead, and the question makes no sense without it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I found a working link (looks like it matches the full list in ikegami's answer) and added a copy of the image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**They are old versions of the tap symbol.**

As it is explained in [this article posted on Daily MTG](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtgcom/arcana/604), the symbol with the T is the tap symbol from Revised through Fallen Empires and the one with the rectangle is the tap symbol from 4th Edition through Scourge.

The article includes an image with old versions of [Royal Assassin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRoyal%20Assassin%5d) making it pretty intuitive that they're tap symbols:

[image]

Comment: Do you know what the ones are between the phyrexian mana at the end and `100`?

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer The first is the chaos symbol from the [planechase dice](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/51), and the half-mana symbols were on some Unhinged cards - [Little Girl](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74257) and [Mons's Goblin Waiters](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=73957).

Answer (score 12):

1st row:

- Generic mana costs (0..9) (and for smaller numbers, colorless mana in mana abilities on cards before the colorless mana symbol was added in Oath of the Gatewatch)

2nd row:

- Generic mana costs (10..19)

3rd row:

- Generic mana costs (20)
- Generic variable mana costs (X,Y,Z)
- Colored mana symbols
- Snow mana symbol (from the Ice Age block)

4th row:

- Hybrids mana symbols

5th row:

- Monocolored hybrid mana symbols
- Phyrexian mana symbols (from the New Phyrexia set)

6th row:

- Tap cost (Current, e.g. [M12's Royal Assassin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=236464))
- Untap cost (from the Shadowmoor block, e.g. [Crackleburr](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crackleburr))
- Colorless mana amount (from the Un- sets, e.g. [Mox Lotus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mox%20Lotus))
- Generic fractional mana cost (from the Un- sets, e.g. [Cheap Ass](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cheap%20Ass))
- **Old icon for tap cost** (e.g. [Revised's Royal Assassin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=1175))
- **Old icon for tap cost** (e.g. [Fourth's Royal Assassin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2124))
- Old white mana symbol (e.g. Alpha's [Blessing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=238))

7th row:

- Generic mana cost (from the Un- sets, e.g. [Gleemax](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gleemax))
- Generic mana cost (from the Un- sets, e.g. [Mox Lotus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mox%20Lotus))
- Chaos symbol (Used in Planechase games, e.g. [Llanowar](http://magiccards.info/extra/plane/planechase/llanowar.html))
- Colored fractional mana symbol (from the Un- sets, e.g. [Little Girl](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Little%20Girl))
- Colored fractional mana symbol (from the Un- sets, e.g. [Mons's Goblin Waiters](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=73957))
- Separator used in the power/toughness box of creatures
- Phyrexian mana symbol (e.g. [Rage Extractor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rage%20Extractor))

Comment: What's a card that has an untap cost?

Comment: @nornagon, [They](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A{Q}&v=card&s=cname)'re all in the Shadowmoor block. Added example to my answer.